# JLabel not showing in Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, null-layout-manager

I'm trying to use the following class as a racket for a simple pinpong game

```
 public class Racket extends JLabel{
        int up, down;
        int x, y;

        public Racket(int up, int down, int x, int y){
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            this.up = up;
            this.down = down;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            setLocation(x,y);
            setOpaque(true);
        }
    }
```

When I add the Racket to the main frame via

```
p1 = new Racket(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, (windowSize.height/2)-10);
window.add(p1);
```

the racket isn't showing up, could anyone point out what's wrong?

The container is just a simple JFrame with no layout manager

```
window = new JFrame("Ping Pong");
window.setSize(500, 500);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: There is no need for your x/y variables. Just use the setLocation() method directly whenever you want to change the location of the racket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And there's your problem:

```
window.setLayout(null);
```

When you use `null` layouts you are fully responsible for the complete layout including the size and location of all added components, and in your code, while you're setting the JLabel's location, you aren't setting the size. The correct solution is not to set its size but to avoid using null layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Since this is for a "ping pong" game which does have random movement of a racket (up and down). I don't have a problem with the usage of the null layout. But you do need to set the size of your racket in the constructor by using the `setSize()` method.

Comment: This indeed was the issue, thank you so much for the help!